# Ionic framework master details dont work with nested json

Tags: json, ionic-framework, factory

I'm new ionic and my concern is to display the details of my data list. I get to display all the elements of my JSON, but I can not for the details. my function "GetPromo" turn me "null". How can I get the "id" of the element "Hotel" in my JSON ? Could you help me ? Thank you

```
var app = angular.module('hotelsApp.controllers', [])

// My factory
app.factory("PromoService", function(){
    var promos = [
   {
      "Hotel":{
         "id":"52",
         "typeEtablissement":"HOTEL",
         "nomHotel":"AUBERGE DES ILES",
         "email":"auberge@ghaima.ci",
         "siteWeb":null,
         "situationGeo":"Assinie",
         "nombreChambre":"12",
         "commune_id":"21",
         "standing_id":"4",
         "prixChambreMin":"5000",
         "prixChambreMax":"15000",
         "tarif":"5 000 \/ 15 000",
         "description":"L'auberge des \u00eeles est un lieu paisible et reposant situ\u00e9 \u00e0 Assinie. Un cadre tout aussi propice \u00e0 l'\u00e9vasion et au loisir, vous accueille pour des s\u00e9jours \u00e0 court moyen et long terme.",
         "typePaiement":"",
         "autreinfo":"",
         "logo":"\/img\/hotels\/52\/logo.jpg",
      },
      "Commune":{
         "id":"21",
         "libelle":"Assinie"
      },
      "Standing":{
         "id":"4",
         "nbEtoiles":"2",
         "libelle":"2 Etoiles"
      },
      "Service":[
         {
            "id":"6",
            "libelle":"Bar",
            "Servicehotel":{
               "id":"1360",
               "hotel_id":"52",
               "service_id":"6"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
];

return {
    GetPromos: function(){
      return promos;
    },
    GetPromo: function(promoId){
      for(var j = 0; j < promos.length; j++) {
        if (promos[j].id === parseInt(promoId)) {
          return promos[j];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
}
});


// My controllers
app.controller('PromosCtrl', function($scope, PromoService) {
  $scope.promos = PromoService.GetPromos();
});

app.controller('PromoCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, PromoService) {
  promoId = $stateParams.promoId;
  $scope.promos[Hotel] = PromoService.GetPromo(promoId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Assuming that your `hotel Id` is `promo Id`, you can access the hotel id with `promos[j].Hotel.id`.

2) The `hotel id` in your json is a string and thus the comparator will evaluate wrongly if you `parseInt` your `promoId`. It will result in `'52' === 52` which evaluates to false.

To sum it up,

```
GetPromo: function(promoId) {
  for (var j = 0; j < promos.length; j++) {
    if (promos[j].Hotel.id === promoId) {
      return promos[j];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```